# Wilson lines, boundary conditions, surface defects of TQFTs

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, topological-field-theory, gauge-invariance

I asked the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/232465/11127) in mathematics stack exchange but I'd like to have answers from physicists too;

I have been studying (extended) [topological quantum field theories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_quantum_field_theory) (in short TQFTs) from the mathematical point of view and I have no background of the physics point of view. Sometimes I encountered papers talking about [Wilson lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_loop), boundary conditions, surface defects and so on. I looked up these terminology but I couldn't find a good explanation how these are related to TQFTs.

Could you suggest me references (papers, websites, books, vidoes etc) that explains the relationship between these physical jargon and TQFTs from mathematical point of view?

Or could you explain it here?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41589/reading-list-in-topological-qft

Comment: They might be related but I don't see how and why. I want to know the specific relation of Wilson lines and TQFTs etc.