# Reference on Chern-Simons theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

I have recently been trying to refresh my memory on the Quantum Field Theory I learned 25 years ago while getting my Ph. D. At the time I did not study Chern-Simons modifications to QFT Lagrangians. Can someone point me to some good notes on the topic? I really want to understand the "utility" of those terms. Why do we want them there?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48514/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41589/2451 and links therein.