# References for Chern-Simons action $ \int d^3 x ~\epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho} A_{\mu} \partial_{\nu} A_{\rho}$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

Can you recommend to me good references on this action? From basics to more advanced stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48514/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41589/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53356/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic this question is much more specific than the general question asking generally about topological QFT, so IMHO it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Abelian CS is usually the first TFT to learn. OP would have to be more specific for this not to be a duplicate.

Comment: Yes; in particular, it should have an explanation of why a generic reference on topological QFT is _insufficient_ for what MathematicalPhysicist is looking for. So the question could be edited so as not to be a duplicate, but in its current form, I think it is a duplicate.