# TQFT lectures with exercises

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, topological-field-theory

I'm interested in topological quantum field theory and study works of Witten and others by myself.
Does anybody know where can I find any good exercises in this subject? By "good" I mean something similar to problems in Francessco-Senechal book on CFT.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41589/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at this lecture notes by Moore and Seiberg:
http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~gmoore/LecturesRCFT.pdf

Answer (score 1):

*Quantum Invariants of Knots and 3-Manifolds* by V.G. Turaev is a great book for this. The treatment is very nice and it usually has several exercises at the end of each section. It is available in Amazon.