# Topological Field Theory for Physicists

Tags: mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, topological-field-theory

I was wondering if anyone knows good resources for Topological Field Theories aimed at physicists. In particular, I am looking for references which are full of examples, starting with simple toy models and building up to more complicated TFTs. I am also looking for references aimed at explaining the subject at someone with a physics background and motivation. For example, a reference with explicit examples building from a Lagrangian that help motivate the more mathematical definitions of TFT. Also, seeing explicitly how one can build explicit examples of these more mathematical definitions from an explicit description of the fields of the theory and an action would be great!

A good example of what I am looking for is this lecture https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqgNrVTQ4yM&t=1498s, which treats free TFTs. Everything can be done explicitely and a lot of important ideas are already present! Having something like this in written form (which would allow to discuss the details) would be great!

Comment: A really good reference that I've found so far but that is still under construction are the notes of Gregory Moore on Chern-Simons theory http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~gmoore/TASI-ChernSimons-StudentNotes.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41589/2451 and links therein.